# NoMethodError in <myController>#<myMethod> undefined method `<myModuleMethod>' for <myModule>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, nomethoderror

orry for the basics, but I'm having a hell of a time getting a very basic flow to work:

1) Define module with a method to save a url to a var (or return it)

2) Call that method in a controller to initialize the method

3) Have a view show that URL

NoMethodError in AuthController#oauth undefined method `oauthurl' for GetAccessToken:Module

Module: \lib\get_access_token.rb

```
module GetAccessToken
    CONSUMER_TOKEN = { :token=>"mytokenstringwhichisreallylong", :secret=> "mysecretstringwhichisreallylong" }
    def self.oauthurl    
      @oauthurl="https://us.etrade.com/e/t/etws/authorize?key=#{(CONSUMER_TOKEN[:token])}&token="
    end
end
```

Controller: app\controllers\auth_controllers.rb

```
require 'get_access_token'
class AuthController < ApplicationController
include GetAccessToken
before_filter :oauthurl1
    def oauthurl1
        GetAccessToken.oauthurl
    end
end
```

View: app\views\auth\oauth.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'oAuth') %>
<h1>oAuth</h1>
<%= link_to "oAuth", @oauthurl %>
```

My higher level goal is to get the eTrade oAuth flow working, but I want to make sure I understand every line of code vs. taking someone else's and I can't get this very basic building block to work yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the generous help of the contributions above, this is how I finally resolved the error.  I defined the instance variable in the controller instead of the model, and initialized the controller method using before_filer:

Model:\lib\test_module.rb

```
module TestModule
    CONSUMER_TOKEN = { :token=>"myReallyLongToken", :secret=> "myReallyLongSecret" }

    def self.testUrl
        "https://us.etrade.com/e/t/etws/authorize?key=#{(CONSUMER_TOKEN[:token])}&token="
    end
end
```

Controller: app\controllers\test_controller.rb

```
require 'test_module'

class TestController < ApplicationController
  include TestModule

  before_filter :testUrl1Init

  def testUrl1Init
    @testurl=TestModule.testUrl
  end
end
```

View: \app\views\test\test.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'test') %>
<h1>test</h1>
<%= link_to "test link", @testurl %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to config/application.rb:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**"]
```

Change your AuthController to:

```
class AuthController < ApplicationController
  include GetAccessToken

  def oauthurl1
    GetAccessToken.oauthurl
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried this permutation as well (adding the config line to application.rb; initializing oauthurl1), but that hasn't worked yet for me either unfortunately - same error.

Answer (score 0):

Your module code will be

```
module GetAccessToken
  CONSUMER_TOKEN = { :token=>"mytokenstringwhichisreallylong", :secret=> "mysecretstringwhichisreallylong" }
  def self.oauthurl    
    "https://us.etrade.com/e/t/etws/authorize?key=#{(CONSUMER_TOKEN[:token])}&token="
  end
end
```

and your controller code should be

```
require 'get_access_token'

class AuthController < ApplicationController
  include GetAccessToken

  def oauthurl1
    @oauthurl = GetAccessToken.oauthurl
  end
end
```

We need to initialize `@oauthurl` in the controller to use this variable in the view, else it will be `nil`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I've moved the included and I forgot to mention I had a before_filter :oauthurl1 line to initialize the @oauthurl method, but I'm still getting the same error with my updated code.

Comment: I ended up using something pretty close to this.  Thanks again for the help!